HP x2 210 G1: Unable to Boot from USB or External Media
I own an HP x2 210 G1 notebook running Windows 10, but I’ve forgotten the administrator password and can’t access the system. To recover access, I’ve tried booting from external media, but I’ve encountered multiple issues:

I created a Linux bootable USB drive, tested it successfully on another laptop, but on the HP x2 210 G2, it fails with the error:


The selected boot device failed. Press Enter to continue.


I also tried using an external DVD drive with a USB connector to boot a Linux DVD and Hiren’s BootCD, but the same error occurred.
The BIOS (InsydeH2O F.02) seems very limited—there is no option to switch between Legacy and UEFI boot modes.
I created bootable USB drives using both Legacy and UEFI options, but neither worked. The notebook refuses to boot from a USB drive or an external CD/DVD drive.
I thought a BIOS update might help, so I downloaded the latest BIOS .exe file. However, when running the utility on another laptop, the "Next" button was grayed out, so I couldn’t create a bootable USB for the update.


Questions:

How can I successfully boot from external media on this device?
Could a BIOS update resolve this issue, and how can I create a bootable USB for the update?

Thank you for your assistance!
